# set variable value to jquery message + jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How to get value of var `total` in message,

and **also i tried declare inside function but it gives undefined variable**

```
var total = '';
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
    var fund_old = $("#current_fund").val();
    var fund_new = $("#new_fund").val();

    total = parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat(fund_old);

    if (parseFloat(fund_new) <= parseFloat(total)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, 'sry sktiman' + total + 'is remaining value');
```

**In result i am getting blank value of total**

Comment: Have you checked that `$("#current_fund").val()` gives you any/correct value?

Comment: @Akshay it is already set

Comment: Please show the HTML markup and the call to `.validate()`.

Comment: Your whole approach to using custom validators with `addMethod` is deeply flawed. These validators are supposed to be reusable, but yours will always do the same, comparing the values of `#current_fund` and `#new_fund`. I'd suggest to start over again, read [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) and have a look at some of the demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line **function() {return 'sry sktiman' + total + 'is remaining value'}** as your second argument, you can easily use this variable

```
var total = ''; 
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
//Your default code here
}, function() {return 'sry sktiman' + total + 'is remaining value'});
```

Comment: can you explain more it ?

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation for [`jQuery.validator.addMethod()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) you can use [`jQuery.validator.format()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/) which generates a function that receives the arguments to the validation method and returns a string message, so creating a function that ignores any arguments and returns a string should work:

```
var total = '';
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
    var fund_old = $("#current_fund").val();
    var fund_new = $("#new_fund").val();

    total = parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat(fund_old);

    if (parseFloat(fund_new) <= parseFloat(total)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, function() {return 'sry sktiman' + total + 'is remaining value'});
```

---

**EDIT**

The fiddle for this solution can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/eZm7x/3/)** (thanks to Sparky for providing the code).

Comment: @Sparky Yes, it does, you just have to declare the `total` var in the global scope, as the OP did. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZm7x/3/).

Answer (score 6):

The optional parameters can be used inside the message.

The third argument, the optional parameters, (you call it `arg`) can be represented within your code as `arg[0]`, `arg[1]`, etc.

Then the corresponding values can be used in your message as `{0}`, `{1}`, etc.

Do your calculation external to `.addMethod()` and pass the value in using the `arg` argument.

```
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){

    var fund_old= $("#current_fund").val();
    var fund_new =$("#new_fund").val();

    // do this calculation where the rule is declared. See 'validate()'
    //total =  parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat(fund_old);

    if(parseFloat(fund_new) <= parseFloat(total)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},'sry sktiman {0} is remaining value');
```

Since you didn't show your `.validate()` or the HTML markup, maybe something like this...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        fund_old: {
            // your rules
        },
        fund_new: {
            valueNotEquals: function() {
                return ($parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat($("#current_fund").val()));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Crude demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/eZm7x/**

Comment: I prefer this parameter way. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var total = '';
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  var fund_old= $("#current_fund").val();
  var fund_new =$("#new_fund").val();

 total =  parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat(fund_old);

      if(parseFloat(fund_new) <= parseFloat(total)){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
 return true;
 },'sry sktiman'+ (parseFloat(9999999999.999999) - parseFloat($("#current_fund").val())) + 'is remaining value');
```

Answer (score 1):

In [addMethod Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod) says: "Add a custom validation method. It must consist of a name (must be a legal javascript identifier), a javascript based function and a default string message."

So, you are adding a custom **validation function** to plugin, and **NOT** executing that function.

Try to set a field with your custom validation and fill that field to run your custom function. Just **AFTER** that check `total` var value.